# Approaches to combining analysis with combinatorics and number theory?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I hope this questions fits the site. I am interested in various methods of combining analysis with combinatorics and number theory. What I mean by this is that (at least to me) at first I wouldn't believe you could use one in the other. So I was overjoyed when I learned about generating functions (This would be we my example of combining analysis with combinatorics), and I'm now equally amazed when studying about analytic number theory (although I'm just starting).

So what are the methods were we put analysis to work in those subjects?
I'm not exactly sure how to tag this so I'd be happy to approve any edits.

Something I'm hoping to see: I've heard rumors of uses of complex analysis in diophantine equations, holy crap....

To sum it up, I want general methods of gaining deep insights by analysis.

Comment: This almost seems like it should be two (still very broad) questions. Anyway, it's demanding but the place where a lot of people get their start on the number theoretic side is Part II of Serre's _A Course in Arithmetic_.

Answer (score 0):

Analytic properties of generating functions gives all kinds of information about asymptotic analysis of counting patterns. Check out this [book](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf) for some specific ideas.

Comment: Got it from the library already, it's part of why I'm asking the question, I want to see other stuff as well!

Comment: I would suggest looking closely at the bibliography of that book. It is going to be referencing all kinds of great sources. Another way analysis is used in combinatorics is via the probabilistic method. A great book to look at is https://www.amazon.com/Probabilistic-Method-Noga-Alon/dp/0470170204

Comment: Thank you I'll check it out